# How To Properly Call a Method From a Mocked Method in Google Test/Mock

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

In Gmock, I'm trying to get a mocked method to sleep for a few milliseconds and then call a method in the Class under Test. Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
EXPECT_CALL(mockedClass, mockedMethod())
        .Times(1)
        .WillOnce(DoAll(Wait(100), ClassUnderTest.MethodToCall()));
```

I've defined `Wait()` a little higher up as:

```
ACTION_P(Wait, ms) { Sleep(ms); }
```

The problem is that I can't seem to get away from this compiler error:

```
Error C2664: cannot convert argument 2 from 'const Action2' to 'const testing::Action<F>&'
```

I just started using Google Test/Mock recently and nothing I've tried or can find seems to do anything about the problem.

**Can anyone help me understand how to properly call a method from a mocked method in Google Test/Mock?**

Comment: What is `ClassUnderTest`?

Comment: Be careful when setting the tags! What does [gmock], a mocking framework for Groovy, have to do with Google mock?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @273k. Google Mock is also called gMock all over their documentation, so I guess I just added the tag without bothering to look at the description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [InvokeWithoutArgs](http://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cook_book.html#invoking-a-functionmethodfunctorlambdacallback-without-arguments), smth like this:

```
EXPECT_CALL(mockedClass, mockedMethod())
        .WillOnce(DoAll(Wait(100), InvokeWithoutArgs([&ClassUnderTest]() { ClassUnderTest.MethodToCall(); } ));
```

`Times(1)` is not needed with `WillOnce`.

Comment: This works great! I had tried out @Ari's idea first, but found out that one has to use some kind of function wrapper like this.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do both function calls with [InvokeWithoutArgs](http://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cook_book.html#invoking-a-functionmethodfunctorlambdacallback-without-arguments):

```
EXPECT_CALL(mockedClass, mockedMethod())
        .Times(1)
        .WillOnce(DoAll(InvokeWithoutArgs(Sleep(100)),
                        InvokeWithoutArgs(ClassUnderTest.MethodToCall())));
```

Comment: So I had tried something similar before, but I tried it again just to see and I keep getting this error for both method calls. ```no instance of overloaded function matches the argument list. argument types are: (void)```

Comment: So I played around with things a bit and landed on something similar that manages to compile. Instead of ```InvokeWithoutArgs(ClassUnderTest.MethodToCall())``` I used ```InvokeWithoutArgs(std::bind(&ClassUnderTestName::MethodToCall, &classUnderTest))```. I still have some unrelated problems, but it seems at least when the method you want to call has no arguments, you need to convert it into something that is Invokable by Google Mock.